# second order linear ODE general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a second order linear ODE of the form $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=r(t)$, if $y_1(t)$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation, and let $y(t)=v(t)y_1(t)$. Can we find a $v(t)$ such that $y(t)$ is also the general solution of the ode?

I think the answer is yes. As  $y_1''+p(t)y_1'+q(t)y_1=0$, $y(t)=v(t)y_1(t)$, we can plug $y(t)$ into $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=r(t)$.

$$v''(t)y_1(t)+v'(t)[2y_1'(t)+p(t)y_1(t)]+v(t)[y_1''(t)+p(t)y_1'(t)+q(t)y_1(t)]=r(t)$$

Since $y_1''+p(t)y_1'+q(t)y_1=0$, then $v''(t)y_1(t)+v'(t)[2y_1'(t)+p(t)y_1(t)]=r(t)$

$$v''(t)+v'(t)\left[2\frac{y_1'(t)}{y_1(t)}+p(t)\right]=\frac{r(t)}{y_1(t)}$$

How can I solve this ODE from here? Should I use variation of parameters? How?

Comment: You need to start with the general solution to the homogeneous equation. Namely you need two solutions: $y_h(t) = c_1 y_1(t) + c_2 y_2(t)$. Then you can make the guess $y_p(t) = u_1(t)y_1(t) + u_2(t) y_2(t)$ for the nonhomogeneous problem.

Comment: @JeremyUpsal could you elaborate on that? I think I already have the homogeneous solutions $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)=y(t)=v(t)y_1(t)$

Comment: You must allow both terms, $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ in your variation of parameters formula. For instance, if the homogeneous solution was $y_h(t) = c_1 \cos(t) + c_2 \sin(t)$, you could not use just $\sin(t)$. In particular, you would run into trouble with the following example: $p=0, q=1, r(t) = \sin(t)$ (work it out on your own, either using variation of parameters or undetermined coefficients).

Comment: Yes. This is the reasoning behind the method of variation of parameters.